# Internet (Flash) video without a PC

Tags: flash, htpc, xbox360, appletv, playstation

I am looking to retire my HTPC. So much of what we do with it can be done with one of our video game consoles or an AppleTV that is seems like a waste of space, power and time to maintain. The trouble is that my wife does streaming yoga classes served up via specific websites. I am assuming they are Flash based and so far I have been unable to find Apps for these content providers.

My question is, is there a *GOOD* way to handle flash-based or even HTML5/h.264 web content with one of the other Internet enabled devices in our stack?

So far we have:

- Nintendo Wii
- Playstation 3
- XBox 360

And we're looking to purchase a current generation AppleTV.

**update** 
The sites are YogisAnonymmous.com and YogaJournal.com, both are confirmed as Flash.

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak to the specifics regarding this Yoga website, without a link or more information.  That said...

... according to Nintendo, regarding Flash on the Internet Channel...

> The Internet Channel will display video in Flash, version 8 or earlier. All other video types, such as QuickTime (.avi) and Windows Media Video (.wmv) will not display. Flash movies made in a version of Flash higher than 8 will not play.

... regarding Streaming content...

> The Internet Channel will display video and audio in Flash, version 8 or earlier. All other types of streaming video and audio are not supported (mp3, streaming news, etc.).

[Nintendo Support](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/wii/en_na/gi_channels.jsp?menu=internet)

The Playstation 3 and flash?  well...

> The PlayStation®3 system’s Internet Browser now supports Adobe Flash Player 9.

[Playstation 3 features](http://us.playstation.com/ps3/features/ps_ps3_softwareupdates.html)

As far as the XBox360 is concerned, their Apps don't support a general web browser, and there is no official support for Flash on the XBox.
[XBox Support](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/apps/browse)

Of course, there are people flashing their XBox consoles and porting all kinds of unsupported Apps... but who knows whether that will support what you are looking for.

At any rate... there is one key element to your question, and I quote...

> I am assuming they are Flash based

Before you go looking for Flash support for these devices, you should have **confirmed** whether or not the site was flash based.

Comment: Thanks Bon. I updated with question. I was able to confirm that both sites my wife uses are flash based.

Comment: At this point, it is also a matter of finding out what version of flash is required to view the sites your wife uses.  For example, if the site requires the most up to date version of Flash... Flash 11... then you would be out of luck with both the Wii and the Playstation 3.  The truth is, you appear to need versatility, and when it comes to versatility, nothing beats a PC.